# Why I can't duplicate OpenSK key

Tags: fido2

I am curious about why I can't duplicate the [OpenSK](https://github.com/google/OpenSK) key.
I have a few keys that I put the same certificate and private key on them but they are different.

I found it useful to have a duplicate key in case of hardware failure, breaking, losing, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't"?

Comment: I create 3 keys with same certificate and pk. For example, I want to register a key in my google account and use any of my key to authenticate ( same certificate on all keys ). I can't do that, google says that is a different key